# CONCATENATE formulas

Tags: excel-2007

I have used the following formula to combine text strings into a new cell and am getting FALSE in my result cell.

=CONCATENATE(LEFT(D2,3),A2)

I am trying to create a unique reference number combining the first three characters of a client name to an entry number.

The formula box shows me the correct answer but is displays as FALSE in my result cell and I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: What is the Value in D2?

Answer (score 0):

try the following formula instead:

```
=MID(D2,1,3) & A2
```